# AlertDialog erro de acentuação ANDROID

Tags: android

Pessoal to tendo problemas com o `AlertDialog`, quando aberto ele exibe as acentuações e nem cedilha, no lugar aparece aquele velho "triangulo com interrogação dentro". O que fazer para resolver?

```
public void alertaInternet(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Definindo Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Sem conexão a internet!");

    // Definindo Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("O aplicativo precisa de conexão a internet para prosseguir.");

    // Ao pressionar o botão OK
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Fechar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Mostrando Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Poste o código que você está usando.

Comment: pronto, já editei acima.

Comment: Já tive esse problema usando o Android Studio, eu criei a mensagem no meu string.xml e recuperei pra exibir.

<string name="mensagem">O aplicativo precisa de conexão a internet para prosseguir.</string>

alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.mensagem));

Comment: Consegui resolver mudando a decodificação do arquivo de "windows-1252" pra "UTF-8".